# Anything I can do to improve my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA macro to auto-delete some rows,
Not sure why it never ends processing.

Could it be a mistake in my code?

Appreciate any help.

```
Sub AutoProcess()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim Row, RowCount

RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Row = 3 To RowCount
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 7).Value = 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 9).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Row).Delete
        RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Row = Row - 1
    End If
Next Row

MsgBox ("finished")

Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Reverse the For loop so you go from `RowCount` to `0` - then you don't need to reset `RowCount` and you don't need to do `Row = Row - 1`. Less lines coded usually means a lower likelihood for bugs.

Comment: Just to double check - you *do* want to check "value is `0`", and not "cell is blank" (`ActiveSheet.Cells(Row,7).Value = ""`)?  Try stepping through 1 line at a time with F8 to see where it goes wrong, and possibly use `Debug.Print Row & " : " & ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 7).Value & " , " & ActiveSheet.Cells(Row,9).Value` to check the values before you do your `If` statement

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes! Thats is a really good idea. thank you

Comment: @Chronocidal i do want to check if its 0 not blank, good idea step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using union for speed

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Using_Loops()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        For r = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 3 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(r, 7).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(r, 9).Value = 0 Then
                If c Is Nothing Then Set c = ws.Rows(r) Else Set c = Union(c, ws.Rows(r))
            End If
        Next r

        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Delete
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Finished", 64
End Sub
```

Another faster approach is to use AutoFilter. Suppose Headers in row 2

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Using_AutoFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        With ws.Range("G2:I" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter 1, "="
            .AutoFilter 3, "="
            If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(12).Count > 1 Then
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Finished", 64
End Sub
```

And here's a third approach using Evaluate to get the rows to be deleted

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Using_Evaluate()
    Dim x, ws As Worksheet, r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With ws
            Set r = .Range("G3:G" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)
            x = Filter(.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF((" & r.Address & "=0)+(" & r.Offset(, 2).Address & "=0),""A"" & ROW(" & r.Address & ")))"), False, False)
            If UBound(x) = -1 Then Exit Sub
            .Range(Join(x, ",")).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Row = RowCount to 3 Step -1
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 7).Value = 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 9).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next Row
```

Comment: I learnt from Stack Overflow >> Never to use `activesheet` and its better to use a variable for the sheet. Its really helpful.

Comment: Thank you, good to know should avoid activesheet. However row=row-1 is for, when a row is deleted, i assume all the following row would move one row upwards (maybe im wrong? Need test)

Comment: You dont need Row = Row-1 in code above if you are using step-1 and moving upward from the bottom row

Comment: Ah, you are calculating backwards! Sure it is a better idea than mine

Answer (score 0):

you could use a "helper" column and a formula

```
With Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
    With .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(SUM(RC7,RC9)=0,1,"""")"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Delete
        .Delete
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a filter rather than looping.
I've also used `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` rather than `UsedRange` as that can return incorrect results.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Set wrksht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With wrksht
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds last row in column A containing data.
        With .Range("A3", .Cells(lLastRow, 9))
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="0"
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
        End With
       .Range("A4", .Cells(lLastRow, 9)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```